# angular2 - how to build with cli - main.bundle.js shows all secrets

Tags: angular

I have a angular2 app hosted on s3 with a flask api authenticated with JWT.

This is how I build for dev env:

```
 ng build -dev
```

if I go to:

```
  https://test.com/main.bundle.js
```

and I view the file I see way too much un-encrypted JS functions and logic about the website my comments etc..

Why does that happen?  This is way too scary...

How do I fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your dev enviroment, it should be OK to see your code for debugging purposes. When you deploy to your prod environment, use following command

`ng build --prod`

Comment: in prod I see a file that looks like this - main.0a23b93a35351399c8e1.bundle.js

Comment: Yeah, that's expected outcome. Angular adds a checksum value to file names. Check it's content. It should be minified and uglified.

Comment: where can i find more info about the uglified?  How secure is the ability for the uglified code from being translated for get info for back info abouj\t code for this that dont have log in creds